# i got a name field which got some special characters like . ,.I want to remove them

Tags: informatica

I used `reg_extract(field,'[A-Za-z0-9]','')` function.It worked but i'm not getting my output. Example if i have a name field has names like this

```
XXXXX, Yyycc
```

(both upper and lower cases). So i used a variable port to change it to upper and then i applied `reg_extract`. I'm getting only the first part of the name like

```
XXXXX.
```

If i got a name like this

```
(abcd,bce)
```

then my output is `abcdc`.I don't know why it skipped the other part of the name.I also tried `replacechr` but i'm getting the same output.

Comment: try this `REG_EXTRACT(input,[A-Za-z0-9])`

Comment: It says invalid token @abhis

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

Use this to remove special characters in a String:

```
REPLACECHR (0, INPUT, REPLACECHR ( 0, INPUT, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 ', '' ), '')
```

And `REG_EXTRACT` is used to extract one of the matching pattern form a regular expression. By default it will extract the first pattern.

Comment: I don't know why is that happening

Comment: For example if i have a name like arun,kumar,n.It's showing me only arunkum

Comment: Edited now (Added the Space ' '). Also Change your data type precision it may be String(10) by default

Comment: The above expression will give result like this: If the Input is "Ar$u#,n K%$um.a,,r" and the Output will be Arun Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Please use this function it will work.

```
REG_REPLACE(field,'[^A-Za-z0-9]' ,'')
```

I am using the same function it's working for me.